# selecting path in chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry

Tags: filepath, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to open a file in a Chrome packaged-app using chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry() but I can't manage to make the dialog show a suggested filename (passed through suggestedName). That works ok if the file is in home path, but doesn't if I 'suggest' a file that's inside a folder in that same home folder. I'm on LinuxMint.
So:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', suggestedName: "~/log.txt"}, callback) ---> works! but,

chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', suggestedName: "~/foo/log.txt"}, callback) ---> doesn't! It just opens dialog showing home folder. Both file and folder exist.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. The file system API strips path information from the suggested name. Put another way, you can suggest a name but not a path.

We do this for security reasons; we want users to always be choosing the file. If your app has a legitimate reason to suggest a path please file a bug at http://crbug.com, describe your use case and cc me.